# Source of an adage about geologists and their various interpreatations of outcrops

Tags: terminology, history-of-science

I once heard (read? I can't remember) an adage which stated something like this (my recall):

> Show an outcrop to X geologists, you'll end up with X different
> interpretations about its formation.

(I wonder if it was not even Y interpretations, with Y > X.)

I have a hard time finding this online with such generic keywords... As there are several geologists here, I'd like to ask:

- **What is the exact wording of this adage?** (or let's say the most commonly found in the literature, written sources welcomed!)
- **Who first said/wrote it**, if this can ever be tracked?

Comment: someone who doesn't actually know anything about geology?

Comment: @John You mean you disagree with this statement? I kind of agree with it. I just read a 1993 paper where the authors summarize one century of diverse interpretations for the very same outcrop, before giving their own. A 2023 paper has just proposed yet another interpretation... Of course all outcrops are not that complex, some are pretty straightforward to understand, but to me field geology is a discipline which still leaves much room for a diversity of interpretations.

Comment: You could say the same for any doctor diagnosing a disease, any archeologist interpreting a site, or astronomer reconstructing a stellar history, the fact that when you have limited data some difficult examples exist does not undermine the discipline.

Comment: I've heard variations of the adage over the past 30-40 years. Not always in relation to outcrop, but also interpretations of lines of drilling & other things that are open to interpretation by geologists. It's usually of the form *Show an outcrop to X geologists, you'll end up with Y different interpretations about its formation*, where Y is usually 1 or 2 greater than X, but sometimes 3 or 4. I've mostly heard it as a facetious joke or comment. Sometimes geologists have said it about geologists & on other occasions mining engineers have said it about geologists. I don't recall having read it.

Comment: @John Of course, that was not my intention.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for this testimony! I guess the origin will be hard to track down, especially if it has only been an oral tradition...